# Replace a part of string with another

Tags: c#, regex, string

**The problem**

I have two strings s1 and s2

```
string s1 = " characters of a string, creating a new string object. An array  U.A.E of characters is passed to this method to U.A.E specify U.A.E  the characters to be removed. The order of the elements in the character array does not affect the trim operation.";

string s2 =  " An array  UAE of characters is passed to this method to UAE specify UAE " ;
```

I am showing the string s1 in a label . and want to bold the s2 part in s1 .

ie ,   `label1.Text = " characters of a string, creating a new string object. <b>  An array  U.A.E of characters is passed to this method to U.A.E specify U.A.E </b> the characters to be removed. The order of the elements in the character array does not affect the trim operation.";`

I can do it by putting `<b>`  in start and `</b>`  end of s2 .  But there is dots ( ' . ' ) in U.A.E of s1 but in s2 its UAE .

**What i have tried .**

I tried to get first index and last index of words to be replaced .

```
 int x = s1.Replace(".", "").IndexOf(s2);
```

But failed to get last index , as UAE repeats .

i tried to put `<b>  </b>`  for all words in s2 separately. But the words may repeat in s1 .

I Want to know if there is any string function ,By which i can replace the s2 part of s1 with out the unwanted dots

**Note** : UAE is just an example , The dots may come in any words

Comment: Is it specific to these strings, ie is it always "UAE" and "U.A.E" or do you want to cater for any combination that may or may not have dots in it?

Comment: @JamesThorpe   UAE is just an example . the words may change . Dots may come in any words.  But the unwanted letter will be always Dot . It wont change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a general solution for all strings that may or may not contain additional `.` characters, you need to construct a regex on the fly based on the second string:

```
var s1 = "Here is a U.A.E string";
var s2 = "UAE string";

//Find all the characters that need an optional . after them
var r = new Regex(@"(\S)(?=\S)");

//Perform a replace on s2 to create a new regex with optional dots, surrounded by () so we capture it
var r2 = new Regex("(" + r.Replace(s2, @"$1\.?") + ")");
//r2 is now a regex containing "(U\.?A\.?E s\.?t\.?r\.?i\.?n\.?g)"

//Use that regex to perform the actual replace, using the captured group to reinsert
var replacedString = r2.Replace(s1, "<b>$1</b>");
//replacedString contains "Here is a <b>U.A.E string</b>"
```

Comment: Great , Thanks , But want to show the replacedString contains "Here is a <b>U . A . E string</b>" ... ie with dots

Comment: @ASh You're right, thanks.  Have updated it with a different search (now looks for non-whitespace followed by another non-whitespace to decide where to put optional `.`s)

Answer (score 3):

the same thing with a simpler RegEx

```
string s1 = " characters of a string, creating a new string object. An array  U.A.E of characters is passed to this method to U.A.E specify U.A.E  the characters to be removed. The order of the elements in the character array does not affect the trim operation.";
string s2 = " An array  UAE of characters is passed to this method to UAE specify UAE ";        

// regex will ignore any dot in tested string while searching pattern
var regex = new Regex(String.Join(@"\.*", s2.AsEnumerable()));              

var result = regex.Replace(s1, m => "<b>" + m.ToString() + "<b>");
```

Comment: Nice.  Note that this will put an optional `.` before the spaces and first characters of each word as well.  Whether that's an issue or not depends on the input/outputs required...

Comment: @JamesThorpe, yes, it should ignore any dot in s1 when search the pattern s2

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
string s1 = " characters of a string, creating a new string object. An array  U.A.E of characters is passed to this method to U.A.E specify U.A.E  the characters to be removed. The order of the elements in the character array does not affect the trim operation.";

string s2 = " An array  UAE of characters is passed to this method to UAE specify UAE ";

s1 = s1.Replace("U.A.E", "UAE");

s1 = s1.Replace(s2, "<b>"+s2+"</b>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast help , But the UAE is just an example . Dots may come in any words . And i want to display the bold sentence with dots

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace "UAE", with or without dots inbetween the characters, you can use

```
s1 = Regex.Replace(s1, @"(U\.?A\.?E\.?)", "<b>$1</b>");
```

The `\.` searches for a literal `.` (without the `\` it would match any character). The `?` means that the dot is optional.

The brackets are uses to group the matched substring, so that the `$1` in the replacement string can insert that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help , But the UAE is just an example . Dots may come in any words